# In a batch file, combining two strings to create a combined path string

Tags: file, join, batch-file, string, path

I need to take two strings and combine them into a single path string inside a batch file similar to the Path.Combine method in .NET. For example, whether the strings are "C:\trunk" and "ProjectName\Project.txt" or "C:\trunk\" and "ProjectName\Project.txt", the combined path will be "C:\trunk\ProjectName\Project.txt".

I have tried using PowerShell's join-path command which works, but I need a way to pass this value back to the batch file. I tried using environment variables for that, but I wasn't successful. One option for me is to move all that code into a PowerShell script and avoid the batch file altogether. However, if I had to do it within the batch file, how would I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Environment variables you set in a subprocess cannot be passed to the calling process. A process' environment is a copy of its parent's but not vice versa. However, you can simply output the result in PowerShell and read that output from the batch file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('powershell -file foo.ps1') do set joinedpath=%%x
```

Still, since PowerShell needs about a second to start this may not be optimal. You can certainly do it in a batch file with the following little subroutine:

```
:joinpath
set Path1=%~1
set Path2=%~2
if {%Path1:~-1,1%}=={\} (set Result=%Path1%%Path2%) else (set Result=%Path1%\%Path2%)
goto :eof
```

This simply looks at the very last character of the first string and if it's not a backslash it will add one between the two – pretty simple, actually.

Sample output:

```
JoinPath "C:\trunk" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
-- C:\trunk\ProjectName\Project.txt
JoinPath "C:\trunk\" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
-- C:\trunk\ProjectName\Project.txt
```

The code and sample batch file can be found [in my SVN](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/3114146) but are reproduced here since they're quite brief anyway:

```
@echo off
echo JoinPath "C:\trunk" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
call :joinpath "C:\trunk" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
echo -- %Result%

echo JoinPath "C:\trunk\" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
call :joinpath "C:\trunk\" "ProjectName\Project.txt"
echo -- %Result%

goto :eof

:joinpath
set Path1=%~1
set Path2=%~2
if {%Path1:~-1,1%}=={\} (set Result=%Path1%%Path2%) else (set Result=%Path1%\%Path2%)
goto :eof
```

Comment: What if one path contains spaces and is quoted? Do you end up with "c:\trunk space"\project.txt instead of "c:\trunk space\project.txt"

Comment: @Martin: Just try it out, that's why the code is there. And no, you don't. I'm using `%~1` and `%~2` in that subroutine which will strip the quotes around the argument. Of course, you need to quote yourself properly, but that's always the case (e.g. when iterating over files with `for`).

Comment: How can I download your sample batch?

Comment: There seems to be a configuration issue. I'll poke my hoster later; for now I have reproduced the code in the answer. It doesn't contain much more.