# Batch character escaping

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting, escaping

I'm fairly proficient at writing Batch scripts for Windows, but even after all these years how to correctly escape characters puzzles me.  It's especially difficult when trying figure out the correct way to escape a regular expression for use with sed. Is there any tool that can help me?  Perhaps something that allows me to paste in a "normal" string and it spits out the correctly escaped version of that string?

**Update:**   I'm reluctant to give an example because I'm not looking for an answer on how to escape one specific string. I'm also not looking for a solution that will work for one specific app. I'm looking for a tool that will help me get the escape syntax correct for every string I ever need to escape no matter what tool might be consuming it from the command line.

That being said the regex I really want is

```
(^.*)(Form Product=")([^"]*") FormType="[^"]*" FormID="([0-9][0-9]*)".*$
```

Take that true regex (i.e. unescaped as far as BATCH is concerned) and wrap it in some sed syntax such as `ssed "s@ --- Insert escaped regex here ---      @http://psph/\1/\2@g" "%~1"` and finally escape it... Again, is there any tool that can assist in escaping any string for use on the BATCH command line?

p.s. There are so many exceptions to BATCH's escaping syntax that I'll even settle for a good cheat sheet.

Comment: @Pacerier I have been writing batch scripts in DOS, etc since 1986 (and assembler, C, C++, etc), and then moved to unix, and am now forced for a moment to come back.  The question asked by the OP is not an oxymoron; the answer below is proof thereof.  Batch was always a dark art.

Comment: To truly understand batch escaping, you must absorb and understand phases 1, 2, 4, 5, 5.3, and 6 of the cmd.exe batch parser, described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053. And for good measure you should also understand the slight differences that apply to command line mode. And that only explains the parsing of cmd.exe itself, and all of its internal commands. Every external command may have additional escape rules that are totally different.

Comment: Closely related: [using batch echo with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7308586)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As [dbhenham points out in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping/16018942#comment96708694_16018942), a (MUCH) more detailed answer can be found in portions of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/173497) (originally by another user jeb and significantly edited and updated by dbhenham since) on a related but much more general question:

- [parsing - How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)

Note that, per dbhenham, this answer is:

> incorrect, misleading, and incomplete

I think this answer is still good enough, for almost all cases, but a careful reading of the above answer might be warranted depending on one's exact character escaping needs and the limitations of this answer.

The remaining has been adapted with permission of the author from the page [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) on [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/).

### TLDR

[Windows (and DOS) batch file character escaping is complicated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/29/9914426.aspx):

> > Much like the universe, if anyone ever *does* fully come to understand Batch then the language will instantly be replaced by an infinitely weirder and more complex version of itself. This has obviously happened at least once before ;)

### Percent Sign `%`

`%` can be escaped as `%%` – "May not always be required [to be escaped] in doublequoted strings, just try"

### Generally, Use a Caret `^`

These characters "may not always be required [to be escaped] in doublequoted strings, but it won't hurt":

- `^`
- `&`
- `<`
- `>`
- `|`

**Example:** `echo a ^> b` to print `a > b` on screen

`'` is "required [to be escaped] only in the `FOR /F` "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), **unless** `backq` is used"

`` ` `` is "required [to be escaped] only in the `FOR /F` "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), **if** `backq` is used"

These characters are "required [to be escaped] only in the `FOR /F` "subject" (i.e. between the parenthesis), **even** in doublequoted strings":

- `,`
- `;`
- `=`
- `(`
- `)`

### Double Escape Exclamation Points when Using Delayed Variable Expansion

`!` must be escaped `^^!` when delayed variable expansion is active.

### Double Double-Quotes in `find` Search Patterns

`"` → `""`

### Use a Backslash in `findstr` Regex Patterns

- `\`
- `[`
- `]`
- `"`
- `.`
- `*`
- `?`

### Also

Rob commented further on this question (via email correspondence with myself):

> As for the answer, I'm afraid the chaos is even worse than the original poster realizes: requirements for escaping parentheses also depend on the string being inside a code block or not!
>
> I guess an automated tool could just insert a caret before every character, then doubling all percent signs - and it would still fail if the string is doublequoted!

Further, individual programs are responsible for parsing their command line arguments so some of the escaping required for, e.g. for `sed` or `ssed`, may be due to the specific programs called in the batch scripts.

Comment: I have always found Rob Vanderwoude's web site to be an excellent reference for learning BATCH and have read many sections of it, but somehow I never read that section. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Rob's explanation beats ss64.com hands down.

Comment: What about spaces (say, in file paths that are used as parameters for calling a batch script (from another batch script))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen You don't have to *escape* spaces but you do have to quote strings that contain them (as otherwise they're interpreted as separate strings).

Comment: That is problematic if it is folder paths (say, partial folder paths) that are going to be combined with other items in the called script - the quotes are not stripped. I ended up using environment variables instead to pass the necessary information. That is another reason for using PowerShell instead, but there is the learning curve (the investment to be made).

Comment: I will post a question about this if I can't find a duplicate (but surely it must exist 7 years after Stack Overflow was lauched?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen – [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3114237/173497) seems to cover what you're trying to do.

Comment: Though this is a good start, there are lots of incorrect, misleading, and incomplete statements in this answer (and Rob Van der Woud's site). For a true understanding, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/1012053.

Comment: @dbenham That's a great answer. Obviously Rob triggered the 'instance replacement' property. Hopefully that other answer will remain *incomplete enough* that it avoids also becoming "incorrect, misleading, and incomplete" like this one has.

Answer (score 8):

The escape character for batch is the caret (`^`). If you want to include any of the pipeline characters in your script you need to prefix the character with the caret:

```
:: Won't work:
@echo Syntax: MyCommand > [file]

:: Will work:
@echo Syntax: MyCommand ^> [file]
```

Comment: Yes, the caret is my goto escape character, but it's not the only escape character in BATCH. Sometimes the escape character is backslash, sometimes it is percent, other times it is double-double quote. Not confused yet? There's more. Sometimes the escape character(s) is double percent. Once in a while it's a combination of caret and percent. See why I'm looking for a helper tool?

Comment: Can you please give some examples of where you use something other than the caret to escape characters in Windows BATCH?

Comment: Here's one Patrick... in this line I use both ^ and '%%' `echo if %%errorlevel%% neq 0 echo Problem moving [filename].txt ^>^> Log.txt >> some.bat` There I'm writing error checking and reporting into one batch file from another. The ^ in front of %errorlevel% won't work, you need the %%errorlevel%% for it to come out correctly in the new batch.

Comment: @PatrickCuff, What other "pipeline characters" are there besides `>`, `<`, `&`, and `|`?

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use an external file as input for sed.

Or using strings directly in batch, it's a good idea to use the delayed expansion.

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "regEx=s/^#*$/""/g"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
sed !regEx! file.txt
```

**EDIT: How to use *unmodified* strings with a batch**

This uses findstr to get the string directly from the batch and return it into a result-variable.
So you can use the sed-string as is.

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM SedString1#(^.*)(Form Product=")([^"]*") FormType="[^"]*" FormID="([0-9][0-9]*)".*$

call :GetSEDString result SedString1
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo the sedString is !result!
sed !result!
goto :eof

:GetSEDString <resultVar> <searchName>
:: Search the own batch file for <searchName> in a line with "REM <searchName>#"
:: Return all after the "#" without any modification
setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G in (`findstr /n /c:"REM %~2#" "%~f0"`) do (
    set "str=%%G"
)
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!str:*#=!"

for /F "delims=" %%A in ("!str!") DO (
  endlocal
  endlocal
  set "%~1=%%A"
  goto :eof
)

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to preserve all command line arguments is to use `%*`: it returns the whole command line starting at the first command line argument (in Windows NT 4, `%*` also includes all leading spaces) and excluding any output redirection.

For example, given this `test.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo Parameters are [%*] end params
```

if you run: `test.bat qwe  rt ":' *" ? (=)`

you get: `Parameters are [qwe  rt ":' *" ? (=)] end params`

Comment: I noticed that, after over 4 years, this answer still has zero upvotes (as of this writing).  Can you provide an example to explain exactly what you mean?