# Cmd Isql Less Operator

Tags: sql, windows, cmd, firebird, isql

I have a firebird database and I'm trying to do something. When i try this command it's not working.

```
echo DELETE FROM TXN WHERE SALESBEGIN < current_date - 2;" | isql -u sysdba -p masterkey localhost:C:\aaa.fdb
```

The `SALESBEGIN` column is of type `DATETIME`

but when i delete "<" operator its working. How can i fix it? This is output;

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin>echo "DELETE FROM TXN 
    WHERE SALESBEGIN < current_date - 2;" | isql -u sysdba -p masterkey 
    localhost:C:\aaa.fdb
    Database:  localhost:C:\aaa.fdb, User: sysdba
    SQL> CON> Expected end of statement, encountered EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `<` which is the redirection character for the command line. You need to escape that using `^`.

However, according to [this site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

> When a pipe is used, the expressions are parsed twice. First when the expression before the pipe is executed and a second time when the expression after the pipe is executed. So to escape any characters in the second expression double escaping is needed

So you need three `^` characters to escape the `<` sign:

```
echo DELETE FROM TXN WHERE SALESBEGIN ^^^< current_date - 2; | isql -u sysdba -p masterkey localhost:C:\aaa.fdb
```

---

In my experience things like that are **much** easier if you simply put the statements into a SQL script and then run that script. In `isql` that would be `isql -i delete.sql`

If you still want to keep everything in a single batch file, you could do something like this:

```
echo DELETE FROM TXN WHERE SALESBEGIN ^< current_date - 2;> _temp_delete.sql 
isql -i _temp_delete.sql -u sysdba -p masterkey localhost:C:\aaa.fdb
```

You still need to escape the `<` in there but only once as the `|` is not involved.

---

See also [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6828751/330315) for more information on how to escape special characters on the Windows command line or batch scripts.

Comment: It didn't work.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin>echo DELETE FROM TXN WHERE SALEBEGIN ^< current_date - 2; | isql -u sysdba -p masterkey localhost:C:\aaa.fdb
Database:  localhost:C:\aaa.fdb, User: sysdba
SQL> Statement failed, SQLCODE = -104
Dynamic SQL Error
-SQL error code = -104
-Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 36
SQL>
C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin>`

Comment: @lilrevo: try `>` instead of the `|` to "send" the statement to `isql`.

Comment: When I change `<` operator to the `=` operator, script is working. The problem is only `<` and `>` operators.