# AzCopy copy run from a batch file in Windows command prompt failure

Tags: azure, azcopy

I'm using AzCopy to copy a file from local server to Azure and coming up with the following failed operation is the command is run from a batch file. If the same command is run from the command prompt the operation is successful.

---

## Run from a batch file - fails:

C:\ftp>AzCopy /Source:C:\ftp\ /Dest:"https://companystrg01.file.core.wind
ows.net/bss?sv=2016-05-31&si=bss-supersecretstring" /S

Incomplete operation with same command line detected at the journal directory "C
:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy", do you want to resume the operation?

Choose Yes to resume, choose No to overwrite the journal to start a new operation. (Yes/No) y

[2018/03/19 13:50:22][ERROR] C:\ftp\board\file.TXT: The transfer fail
ed.

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
HttpStatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value
 of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:

Time:Mon, 19 Mar 2018 03:50:05 GMT
Finished 0 of total 1 file(s).
[2018/03/19 13:50:22] Transfer summary:

Total files transferred: 1

Transfer successfully:   0

Transfer skipped:        0

Transfer failed:         1

Elapsed time:            00.00:00:04

================================

## Run form a command line - succeeds:

C:\ftp>AzCopy /Source:C:\ftp\ /Dest:"https://companystrg01.file.core.wind
ows.net/bss?sv=2016-05-31&si=bss-supersecretstring" /S

[2018/03/19 13:56:57][WARNING] The command line "AzCopy /Source:C:\ftp\board\ /D
est:"https://companystrg01.file.core.windows.net/bss?sv=2016-05-31&si=bss-supersecretstring" /S" in the journal file "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\
Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy\AzCopy.jnl" is different from your input.

[2018/03/19 13:56:57][WARNING] Incomplete operation with different command line
detected at the journal directory "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsof
t\Azure\AzCopy".

Do you want to overwrite the journal to start a new operation? Choose Yes to overwrite, choose No to cancel current operation. (Yes/No) y
Overwrite https://companystrg01.file.core.windows.net/bss/file.TXT w
ith C:\ftp\board\file.TXT? (Yes/No/All) y
Finished 1 of total 1 file(s).
[2018/03/19 13:57:06] Transfer summary:

Total files transferred: 1

Transfer successfully:   1

Transfer skipped:        0

Transfer failed:         0

Elapsed time:            00.00:00:09

C:\ftp>

---

I would appreciate some guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters in your batch file. See a similar question here: [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping)

Answer (score 3):

Simply escape % sign with %% in your SAS token even if it is wrapped within ""!

Answer (score 0):

Now it's not necessary to escape sign % on Windows OS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).