# Loop through text files to find a string batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I want to search all .config files for a string "Hello" and if it is found I want to call the function findString.  If not, I want it to continue searching .config files.

This is what I have and I do not see what the problem is.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions


:TOP
for /R %%f in (*.config) do (
    findstr /i "Hello" "%%f" >NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        call :findString
    ) else (
        goto TOP
    )
    pause 
    exit /b
)

:findString
    set "textfile=%1"
```

Comment: Why not simply use `findstr /IMS "Hello" *.config`

Comment: You are confused on the logic.  You do not need the `ELSE` clause or the `GOTO` or the `EXIT` inside the `FOR` command.  You do need an `EXIT` after the closing parentheses of the `FOR` command.

Comment: You are also confused on the `ERRORLEVEL`. If the string is found the `ERRORLEVEL` will be 0.  So you actually need to do `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL  1`.  Which means if errorlevel is not greater than or equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

Searching recursively in all non-hidden *.config files for a string and replacing it with another string is an easy to achieve task on using [JREPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" (
    echo Batch file "%~nx0" requires batch file JREPL.BAT in
    echo directory: "%~dp0"
    echo/
    echo Please download it from:
    echo/
    echo https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3^&t=6044
    echo/
    echo Extract the batch file in downloaded ZIP archive file into
    echo directory: "%~dp0"
    goto EndBatch
)

set "Search=Hello"
set "Replace=Goodbye"

echo Processing *.config files in entire directory tree starting in:
echo "%CD%"
echo/

set "FilesCount=0"
set "FoundCount=0"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.config /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set /A FilesCount+=1
    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /I /L /C:"%Search%" "%%I" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo File "%%I" does not contain "%Search%".
    ) else (
        set /A FoundCount+=1
        echo File "%%I" contains "%Search%" replaced by "%Replace%".

        rem Replace case-insensitive literally the string "%Search%" by string "%Replace%".
        call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "%Search%" "%Replace%" /I /L /F "%%I" /O -

        rem Insert here more command lines to execute on *.config file
        rem containing literally the string to find in the file.
    )
)
echo/
if %FilesCount% == 1 (set "PluralS=") else set "PluralS=s"
echo Updated %FoundCount% of %FilesCount% *.config file%PluralS%.

:EndBatch
endlocal
echo/
pause
```

The main reason for using

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.config /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do (
```

instead of

```
for /R %%I in (*.config) do (
```

is the fact that the latter does not work correct on drives with [FAT32 or ExFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) file system in case of one directory contains more than one *.config file. On drives with [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) file system the shorter and a bit faster command line using only **FOR** could be used too.

The next solution uses **FINDSTR** to search recursively for *.config files containing literally and case-insensitive the string `Hello` to replace it by `Goodbye`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" (
    echo Batch file "%~nx0" requires batch file JREPL.BAT in
    echo directory: "%~dp0"
    echo/
    echo Please download it from:
    echo/
    echo https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3^&t=6044
    echo/
    echo Extract the batch file in downloaded ZIP archive file into
    echo directory: "%~dp0"
    goto EndBatch
)

set "Search=Hello"
set "Replace=Goodbye"

echo Processing *.config files in entire directory tree starting in:
echo "%CD%"
echo/

set "FoundCount=0"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M /I /L /S /C:"%Search%" "*.config"') do (
    set /A FoundCount+=1
    echo File "%%I" contains "%Search%" replaced by "%Replace%".

    rem Replace case-insensitive literally the string "%Search%" by string "%Replace%".
    call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "%Search%" "%Replace%" /I /L /F "%%I" /O -

    rem Insert here more command lines to execute on *.config file
    rem containing literally the string to find in the file.
)
echo/
if %FoundCount% == 1 (set "PluralS=") else set "PluralS=s"
echo Updated %FoundCount% *.config file%PluralS%.

:EndBatch
endlocal
echo/
pause
```

Of course this solution does not report non-hidden *.config files not containing the searched string as those files are already filtered out by **FINDSTR**.

These two batch files work even on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

Other solutions without using **JREPL.BAT** and with using only very limited capabilities of Windows command processor for string handling can be suggested only on knowing

- [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of the *.config files and
- which lines those *.config files really contain and
- what is the string to search for and
- what is the replace string.

`cmd.exe` is not designed for editing text files. It is designed for running commands and applications. Lots of other scripting languages respectively their interpreters have very easy to use built-in functions to replace strings in one or more files literally or using a regular expression like JScript, PowerShell, Python, Perl, ...

See for example [Modify a string in a .properties file with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319538/) or [Regex in Batch Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311950/) how difficult it is and how much variants can be written for a simple string replace using only the commands **FOR** and **SET** which `cmd.exe` offers for working with strings. The questioners have at least posted what the file to process contains and what they expect from the batch file although a complete list of requirements was also not posted by both questioners.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` (drive and path of batch file ending expanded always with a backslash) and `%~nx0` (only file name and extension of batch file) because of argument 0 is always the batch file.
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

More and better help on Windows commands can be found at:

- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)