# Set a variable to the contents of another variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am attempting to create a program that will essentially "Emulate" variables.

I tried testing this issue with this code:

```
@echo off
set a=b
set b=c
:: The program should echo %b% because it is expanded with double percentages
echo %%a%%
```

the Program only echoes "%%a%%", instead of expanding to %b%, which should result in the program echoing C.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This management is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `call` and use a doubled set of percent signs to get a value of `c`.

```
call echo %%%a%%%
```

Alternatively, you can put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of the script and use `echo !%a%!`

Comment: That still doesn't do what I am asking. When I echoed it, it echoes !b!, instead of expanding !b! into c, which is the contents of b.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. https://i.imgur.com/ALbagx1.png You remembered to enable delayed expansion, right?

Comment: Yes. I did enable expansion.

Comment: If your code looks exactly like it does in the picture I posted, it will work and `c` will get displayed.

Answer (score -2):

From the answer at
[Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping[1])

It appears the formal definition is quite vague:

> May not always be required [to be escaped] in doublequoted strings,
>   just try

Therefore, try unescaped:

```
 echo %a%
```

Comment: I am attempting to echo %b% by echoing the value of %a% like %%a%%, where it will expand the INNER %a% to b, but keep the out percent symbols, which are then expanded to the contents of B.