# Put a variable in a text file as it is (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file

I need some assistance. Is it possible to make it so that this code:

```
@echo off
@title test
(
echo %test%
) >> test.txt
pause
```

Would have this in "test.txt"

```
%test%
```

Instead of this:

```
ECHO is OFF.
```

So basically, I wan't to know if you can put a variable in a text document, without the actual variable showing up in the text document. Thanks

Comment: You can escape `%` with another `%`: `echo %%test%%` Not an answer because I"m sure this is answered already.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/6828751/1531971 among others.

Answer (score 0):

ECHO needs a period following the command to treat the following values as not parameters of ECHO itself. This is correct:

```
echo.%test%
```

This is asking for trouble:

```
echo %test%
```

Comment: plain wrong. The dot just don't give an error message, if the variable is empty

Comment: No, it doesn't. The dot ensures that, I quote, "treat the following values NOT as parameters of ECHO itself." Here's an example you can try to demonstrate this: `set "test=/?"&echo %test%` vs `set "test=/?"&echo.%test%`