# If else loop crashing batch file

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  if [%%j]==[5] set cdletter=%%i
  )


echo %cdletter%

pause


if "%cdletter%"=="" (
echo Device driver not found: 'MSCD000'
echo No valid CDROM device drivers selected
) else ( 
echo MSCDEX Version 2.23
echo Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1986-1993. All rights reserved.
pause
echo        "Drive %cdletter% = Driver MSCD000 unit 0"
)
```

I also ran a another if else like this before it and this one works fine. im not sure why this other one is not working

```
if "%cdletter%"=="" ( 
timeout 2 >nul
echo    No drives found, aborting installation
) else (

chcp 65001 >nul
wmic cdrom where mediatype!='unknown' get name > discinfo.txt
type discinfo.txt > discinfoutf8.txt 
rem F THIS YOU HAVE TO DO THIS BECASUE UTF 16 DOESNT WORK IN A FOR LOOP 

goto driveinfoecho
)
```

this just grabs the cd drive info so i can put it into a variable and use it in an echo command

Comment: What do you think this `(C)` does to your else command? The error message literally says: `Microsoft was unexpected at this time.`.  So that should give you a big clue.

Comment: Try escaping the `(` and `)` in your else with `^(` and `^)`.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping

Comment: Why are you trying to mascaraed as MSCDEX?

Comment: Im trying to make cmd boot like an old dos box

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the advice you've received in the comments, I'd advise that you just omit the `Else` condition completely, and instead close the script if there is no CDROM, or one with an issue.

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Drive=" & For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path
 Win32_CDROMDrive Where "ConfigManagerErrorCode=0" Get Drive 2^> NUL'
) Do For /F Tokens^=* %%H In ("%%G") Do Set "Drive=%%H"
If Not Defined Drive (Echo No properly working CDROM drive found
 Echo Press a key to exit . . . & Pause 1> NUL & GoTo :EOF)
Echo MSCDEX Version 2.23
Echo Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1986-1993. All rights reserved.
Pause
Echo        "Drive %Drive% = Driver MSCD000 unit
```