# AzCopy in Batch file

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Am trying to copy files to Azure Blob using `AzCopy`.

When execute `AzCopy` at command line it works fine, but executing same through .`bat` file getting issues.

ex: `azcopy copy "c:\xxxxxxx\20210304" "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxdrop?sp=rw&st=2021-03-04T05:06:45Z&se=2021-03-04T13:06:45Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoqxx6dJczN26Mc%3D" --recursive`

what is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some special characters in .bat file should be escaped. In the command you provided, the `%` in the sas_token should be replaced by `%%`.

If the issue is that the azcopy command cannot be found, you should specify the full path of the azcopy.exe in your .bat file.

I gave it a try at my side, it works fine in .bat file. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

By the way, here is [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping) about chars-escape in .bat file.

Comment: Thanks Ivan!!   same issue i was facing, your solution worked for me