# Using printf in Windows batch script to write line with special characters

Tags: windows, scripting, printf

I have a simple need to do this in a Windows batch script:

```
set getlock=C:\getlock.awk
if exist %getlock% del %getlock%

echo /^^uq:/ ^&^& /updsync/ {>>%getlock%
echo     printf ("%s^\n", $2)>>%getlock%
echo }>>%getlock%`
```

And want the resulting file to look like this:

```
/^uq:/ && /updsync/ {
    printf ("%s\n", $2)
}
```

However, the batch script fails on the "echo printf" line; although I think I have escaped all necessary special characters?

I have tried many different variations of the printf line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as you did when I tried using your batch file in Windows 10, i.e., the line with `printf` was missing. However, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018942/11726740) to [Batch character escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6828751/11726740) states

> ### **Percent Sign** `%`
>
> `%` can be escaped as `%%` – "May not always be required [to be escaped] in doublequoted strings, just try"

As suggested, I replaced "%s" with "%%s". I also changed "^\n" to "\n" as the "^" was also being output. Thus, that line is now

```ts
echo     printf ("%%s\n", $2)>>%getlock%
```

Running the updated batch file results in the output file

```
/^uq:/ && /updsync/ {
    printf ("%s\n", $2)
}
```

which is what you requested.

Comment: @MikeD You're welcome. I'm glad it worked perfectly for you. Since my answer solved your problem, please consider upvoting (which, unfortunately won't currently do anything because you don't yet have the minimum reputation of 15) and/or accepting it, i.e., clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.